Browser Mobile emulation functionality in my site without using inspect tool
I'm working on a functionality where users can configure a screen and specify the resolution at which the configured screen will be displayed. I've implemented this using a fit layout and grid systems. However, I'm facing an issue with previewing the configured screen on the configuration page itself.
Currently, when the user clicks on the preview button, it opens a full-screen popup and renders the element. The problem arises when the resolution is not a perfect fit, as it either shows scrolls if the resolution is larger or cuts off content if the resolution is smaller.
I noticed that the Chrome DevTools' mobile emulation functionality can scale down/up the page zooming and adjust the height and width accordingly, giving a nearly identical preview of how it will actually look like on that resolution.

I want to integrate this kind of functionality on my website using a library or CSS. I'm using Angular for my project.
Is there a library or CSS technique that can help me achieve this kind of responsive preview functionality?
I have tried to use element's height and resolution and finding scale and adjusting the width and height according to it but it doesn't quite work

var terminalWidth = 4000; // user defined resolution
var terminalHeight = 2000;

const previewHeight = document.getElementById('kioskPreview').clientHeight;
const previewWidth = document.getElementById('kioskPreview').clientWidth;


const scale = Math.min((previewHeight / terminalHeight), (previewWidth / terminalWidth));

this.rendererHeight = (previewHeight * scale) + 'px';
this.rendererWidth = (previewWidth * scale) + 'px';

<div id="kioskPreview" style="height:auto; width:auto">
    <div id="kioskPreviewRenderer" [style.height]="rendererHeight" [style.width]="rendererWidth">
        <my-rendering-component />
        <my-rendering-component />
    </div>
</div>



Your info about how you implemented this lacks detail, but just modifying the dimensions of parts of the content of your main document, is rather unlikely to give you accurate results to begin with - for example any viewport-related media queries will probably not give the desired results then. I'd start by using an iframe for this "responsive preview" - then you can size the viewport properly (the iframe dimensions), and then scale the iframe element itself down, if it does not fit the screen.

I have simply set a css after calling this function nothing more. about iFrame can you give me example. I have edited the question to include a html file also

Just load the page in an iframe so it gets the correct viewport values etc, then resize it with, say, a transform: scale() to make it fit. Whatever you are trying to do here is probably not really a good idea - you cannot change many of the aspects you would need to change, like changing from mouse to touch etc... Why even try to reimplement a perfectly fine function everyone has built-in their browsers, but worse?

@somethinghere i am not trying to make user interactive page here it will just be a preview thing. that how it will look like in actual senario

also, we need to go to inspect element of browser and then set required resolution manually to view the how it will look it will be useful while i'm developing and testing. but in production i can't just ask end user to do all this just to view preview

Then your only solution is to implement an iframe at resolution, then calculate how much you need to scale it down in order fit your screen. scale = Math.min( desiredHeight / iframe.clientHeight, desiredWidth / iframe.clientWidth ) should give you the right "resize" Just make sure the wrapper has overflow: hidden to ensure no unnecessary scrollbars appear.

iframe solution breaks my css style and just renders a text
